# Output for this code doesn't make sense

Tags: c, fork

Given the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
    int i;
    printf("My PID: %d \n", getpid());

    for(i=0; i<3;i++){
        if (fork()==0){
            printf("Son PID: %d\n", getpid());
            return 0;
        }
    }
    while(wait(NULL)!=-1);
    printf("OK!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following output:

```
My PID: 13695 
Son PID: 13696
My PID: 13695 
Son PID: 13697
My PID: 13695 
Son PID: 13698
My PID: 13695 
OK!
```

I have no idea why 'MY PID: 13695' is printed more than once (at the beginning).
What's going on here?

Edit: It works on my system but when I ran it on a few other systems I did get the output as stated above.
For example: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

This is a question I was asked on a test and I'm not sure what the answer is.

Comment: I hate to be the guy, but "works for me", on both Linux with GCC and OS X with clang. What's your environment (OS & C compiler)?

Comment: Works for me too. `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3`

Comment: It works for me as well when I run in on Eclipse. 
When I run it on some other environments (for example: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php) the output is as stated above.

Comment: Sounds like you should file a bug there then

Comment: it's definitely a bug on the way they handle the compiled code

Comment: Could it be that the printing buffer uses wasn't cleared and so each son process prints the parent's buffer as well?

Comment: sent a bug report with this thread through their contact mail form (which does not work)

Comment: It's not a bug in the environment, it's double-flushing of stdout.  Everyone who sees this doing the Right Thing for them, run `./a.out | cat` instead of just `./a.out`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some, but not all, C libraries, detect on the first write to `stdout` whether or not it is connected to a *terminal* (as if by calling [`isatty`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty)).  If it is, they set `stdout` to be *line buffered* rather than *fully buffered*.  On such systems, this program will produce the expected output when (and only when) it is writing to a terminal.  Presumably this "online C compiler" thing is using some other form of IPC to capture the program's output and thus not triggering this special case.  If you see this program produce the expected output, try running

```
$ ./a.out | cat
```

and you will almost certainly see it behave as Shookie describes.

To make the program behave as expected in all contexts, simply insert a call to [`fflush`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) immediately before the `fork`:

```
...
int
main(void)
{
    int i;
    printf("My PID: %d \n", getpid());

    for (i=0; i<3;i++) {
        fflush(0);
        if (fork() == 0) {
...
```

(In *this* case, you could get away with `fflush(stdout)` rather than `fflush(0)` and you could get away with putting it before the loop, but in the general case it needs to be *immediately* before the `fork` call and it needs to flush all open files, not just `stdout`.)

Answer (score 2):

```
% cat > t.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
    int i;
    printf("My PID: %d \n", getpid());

    for(i=0; i<3;i++){
        if (fork()==0){
            printf("Son PID: %d\n", getpid());
            return 0;
        }
    }
    while(wait(NULL)!=-1);
    printf("OK!\n");
    return 0;
}
% gcc t.c
% ./a.out 
My PID: 23382 
Son PID: 23383
Son PID: 23384
Son PID: 23385
OK!
```

My only guess would be that some environment might not flush the buffer from the first `printf` and so the first string is still in memory when the children print the second message and then exit which should cause a buffer flush under any operating environment.

Comment: me too: My PID: 8973 
Son PID: 8974
Son PID: 8975
Son PID: 8976
OK!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that the output buffer hasn't been flushed before the `fork()` call. `fork()` essentially replicates the entire state of the program, including the output buffer, so each child process has the "My PID..." string in its output buffer (note that the PID on that line doesn't change). When the buffer is eventually flushed, you get the entire contents, i.e. the line that the parent process put there.

To fix this (per Zack's comment below), add `fflush(0);` somewhere between the first `printf()` and the `fork()`, so that the output buffer is cleared before being duplicated as a consequence of the `fork()` call.

Comment: which is certainly due to the way compileonline handles input/output from compiled code they run!

Comment: How come this seems to be machine specific?

Comment: One more thing: If I remember correctly the buffer is part of the file object which will be pointed at by all of the child processes. Why then do we see the My PID line more than 2 times? Shouldn't we see it only once more after it'll get flushed by the first child?

Comment: @Shookie `fork` makes a *copy* of the process, so each child process has its *own* copy of the `FILE` object.  (There is also a "file object" inside the kernel, and that *is* shared, but it doesn't hold the buffer at issue here.)

Comment: @Zack As far as I know fork copies the file descriptor table but each child process points to the same file object (there is no need to copy the file object). So I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @Shookie Yeah, that's the kernel's file object you're thinking of, and it does work the way you think it does, but it *doesn't* have any buffers in it (as far as you can tell, anyway).  `stdout`, though, is a C-library-level `FILE` object, which is not at all the same thing.  It *does* have a buffer in it, and it is in the process's address space and it is copied by `fork`, buffer and all.